# Access php through jquery ajax in Sharepoint

Tags: development, jquery, ajax, php

I have the following code within a Sharepoint page

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     url:"http://somesite.ro/helper.php",
     dataType: 'jsonp', // Notice! JSONP <-- P (lowercase)
     success:function(json){
         // do stuff with json (in this case an array)
         alert("Success");
     },
     error:function(){
         alert("Error");
     }      
    });



});
```

When I run it it does not alert neither `error` or `success`.

EDIT: now it gives me error but if I `echo alert("Something");` inside `helper.php`, it prompts me Something within the Sharepoint page. Why is it giving me error instead of success?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The data in the php file was not processed as jsonp because I'm using php 5.1 which doesn't have json_encode function implemented.

So I used `jsonwrapper`: http://www.boutell.com/scripts/jsonwrapper.html

Full php example code:

```
require 'jsonwrapper/jsonwrapper.php';

$array = array(
     '0' => array('fullName' => 'Meni Samet', 'fullAdress' => 'New York, NY'),
     '1' => array('fullName' => 'Test 2', 'fullAdress' => 'Paris'),
);

    if(isset ($_GET['callback']))
{


    echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($array).")";

}
```